# Query keyword and shortCode of a mobile number | Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Does anyone have any idea how to retrieve the mobile numbers by an SQL query using the Automation Studio passing as a keyword parameter or a shortCode.

I just found the _MobileAddress extensions and
_MobileSubscription
but I can not find the Keyword and ShortCode attributes